# CSS Font-size not working properly on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser

I'm working on a small project for school, where we have to incorporate html5 and css3. It's just in the begin stage now, as I'm trying to create two separate css-files for a mobile and a desktop version.

For the mobile version, I'm trying to get the menu to just show as a list, but with a bigger font. I can in no way get this working though.

This is the css for the menu:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav {
    margin-top: -36px;
    width: 100%
}

nav h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

This creates the following on my desktop[image: Desktop with 1em]
And on my iPhone[image: iPhone with 1em]

The font-size is set to 1em in the HTML in the top of the file. But 1em is not big enough for mobile devices, so I want it bigger, which seems impossible.

Even when I give the `nav h1` a font-size of 10em, it doesn't get bigger than this:
[image: iPhone with 10em]

While on my desktop it does work without a problem, there it looks like this:[image: Desktop with 10em]

The same problem occurs when trying to make the "blog posts" bigger, they just won't do it.

I normally have no trouble working with CSS, but this time I can't figure it out. Hope anyone can help! I have the feeling it's something very obvious.

Here is the complete CSS: http://snipt.org/zLic5

Here is the html: http://snipt.org/zLid2

Comment: why not declare the font size in pixels instead of em? on a sidenote, if you use media queries you can stick to one css and only override the styles that are different between devices.

Comment: There is an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750594/maximum-font-size-a-page-can-render.  You put so much effort into asking your question, I can't bring myself to vote to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

i saw your html code. you are not adding any meta tag. certain meta tags are required, when you are developing mobile website,

for example you have to add -

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Welcome to your school name</title>

<!-- smart phone css  -->
<link href="assets/phone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)" />

<!-- Tablet -->
<link href="assets/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 800px)" />

<!-- Desktop -->
<link href="assets/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:801px)">
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer! Adding the meta-tag with the viewport solved the problem! I of course also added the other metas. I'm not using the links to .css, because I'm using @media screen for that, so I just have to keep track of one css.

Comment: @naresh-kumar - Thanks. This helped me out as well. I did notice a typo though, it should be `user-scalable` (no "e"). Cheers

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot and saved me a lot of work

Comment: This is not a good example... In the viewport meta tag only "width=device-width" is needed for the site to scale properly. Also, "maximum-scale=1.0" together with "user-scalable=no" is especially bad in terms of accessibility as this settings block zoom-in. Check: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things I think can help your situation. Semantically, you don't want to use `<h1>` tags in your menu list at all. Remove those tags and apply the styling to the `nav li` css style and adjust the padding accordingly. Also, just a recommendation, but I've heard from a few websites that the ideal mobile font sizing is `pt`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to using the li for you navigation.

Then set the font-size to something acceptable (14px or 16px).

Then, in your css, use media-queries.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { // will only happen on viewport less then 480 pixels (mobile)
  li {
    font-size:18px; // larger font (or whatever you want to do
    padding: 20px; // can even increase your padding
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css property `text-size-adjust` to scale text on mobile devices. Something like:

```
nav {
    text-size-adjust: 200%;
}
nav ul {
    text-size-adjust: 300%;
}
nav h1 {
    text-size-adjust: 400%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issues.  This is experimental by the way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust
Also, I can now see that the default is for different element's font sizes to change by different amounts.  I set this to 250% for the `body` tag so that all elements would scale together.

Comment: please check browser compatibility before trying this solution. As of date, not very well supported

Comment: It is supported by all FF mobile, Chrome and Safari for iOS