# Chromium does not allow font size to be greater than 10000px

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I am evaluating an html file using `puppeteer`. The html is css scale transformed (`transform: scale(0.001);`), so the font sizes given in the styles are larger than normal.

For example in the following image, the font-size specified in css is 11364px. But the computed value is 10000px. It looks like chromium has a maximum font size. So the final output is not as expected. It works in safari without any issues.

I just want to know

1. If this max value of chromium can be increased ?
2. If not can I evaluate and get the actual font-sizes (11364px in this example) using puppeteer. I am able to get the computed values but it only returns 10000px.

   [image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, I'm just curious as to why you'd need something over 10k pixels? [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750594/maximum-font-size-a-page-can-render)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control on the html I receive and some of the html's I get have font-sizes higher but with transform: scale(less than 1), so that it appears small on screen.